# Regex to find data-src attributes with curly braces

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to find a good pattern finding elements looking like this

`data-src="{{xxxx}}"`, the contents in the curly braces may shift

The idea is to get the contents from the data-src on document.ready and insert that into a new src attribute, i.e.

```
$("img:regex(class, EXPRESSION)").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
});
```

Thanks

Comment: i'm not sure, but possibly you need something like: `$("img[data-src^='{{'][data-src$='}}']")`.

Answer (score 3):

Why RexEx? Just not match the start and end of the attribute:

```
$('[data-src^="{{"][data-src$="}}"]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/574u9zh3/

Alternatively, use a RexEx inside a call to `filter()`:

e.g.

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    var attr = $(this).data('src');
    // return true for any RexEx match you care to make
    return ...
}).each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
});
```

Note: For *reading* `data-` attributes, use `data()` instead.

```
$(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
```

Comment: @Grundy: Nice one. I was busy writing the JSFiddle too of course. :)

Comment: Regex is commonly faster than native jquery stuff in my experience, I may be wrong?

Comment: @Eric Herlitz: Depends on the type of search, but that's why I allowed for option 2 if RegEx is needed :)

Comment: ... I like second way.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you absolutely do need regex, it could be something like this:

```
/<[^>]*data\-src="{{(.*)}}">/
```

`<` the opening tag

`[^>]*` any match number of any characters, except a >

`data\-src="{{` the beginning of the data attribute

`(.*)` any number of any characters, capturing the result

`}}">` the end of the data attribute

Comment: He is talking about a jQuery selector, not searching HTML.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Apparently so! My bad. :)